# How to find the record that failed in validation with nested attributes on a has_many association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Let's say I have this:

```rb
class Author < ActiveRecord::Base  
  has_many :posts
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :posts
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base  
  belongs_to :author
  validates_presence_of :name
end
```

The front-end has a form that saves it all at once, with one author and as much post as you want, sending this input:

```rb
attributes = { name: "lorem",
  posts_attributes: [
    { name: 'lorem',
      order: 1 },
    { name: 'lorem',
      order: 2 }
   ] 
}
author = Author.new(attributes)
author.save
```

My question is about validation. How can I send back validation to the front-end so that it can understand in the form which `Post` instance has failed? Right now, with an input like:

```rb
attributes = { name: "lorem",
  posts_attributes: [
    { order: 1 },
    { name: 'lorem',
      order: 2 }
   ] 
}
author = Author.new(attributes)
author.save
```

`author.errors.messages` will return something like `{:"posts.name"=>["must be present"]}` with no indication to know which `name` field it is in the form to send the validation error to, since there are more than one post being created.

How to change this error to get this indication, by maybe using the `order` attribute that each `Post` instance has too?

EDIT : instead of a custom validation error including the number order in the error message, I'd like another key-value pair like `order: 1` so that it is easier to handle in the front-end

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the solution I need: https://bigbinary.com/blog/errors-can-be-indexed-with-nested-attrbutes-in-rails-5

Basically adding `index_errors: true` to the `has_many` association does the trick.

This leads to error to be generated this way, in my usecase: `{:"posts[0].name"=>["must be present"]}`

Comment: great find, this seems to be indeed the proper way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you want to have a more specific validation message you will have to create your own validation function in the `Post` model instead of using the `presence` option.

Post.rb

```
validate :validate_name_present

...

private

def validate_name_present
  return if name.present?
  errors.add(:name, "must be present" + (order.present? ? " for order #{order}" : ""))
end
```

Comment: Is that `order` built in to the nested attributes functionality?

Comment: the `order` is the order parameter that you are passing in your example. you can use any other parameter as well.

Comment: And is it possible to have more of a key / value pair added (like `order: 1`) to the hash instead? to make it easier to handle in the front end?

Comment: Not with this approach

Comment: @DanielSindrestean thanks, I'm not the OP. But this was very helpful. Didn't have enough coffee before I asked my question and didn't see the attrs they were passing the example :P

Comment: @Int'lManOfCodingMystery check the other answer as well, Antoine's answer seems to be the proper way to do it in case you have Rails 5+.